# Como modularizar uma app feita em Sammy.js com Require.js ou "module pattern"?

Tags: javascript, requirejs, módulo-ecmascript

Eu tenho uma aplicação(app mobile) escrita em Sammy.js com 4 rotas.

Cada rota tem de 40 a 70 linhas de código e um `evento bindado`. Escrever tudo num só callback do `app` está virando uma bela macarronada porque esses eventos (`this.bind`) não funcionam no escopo da rota, apenas no escopo global, dai eles se misturam com os `uses`, `arounds`, etc.

Minha intenção é fazer algo similar à modularização do **Express.js** + **Express Load**. Tipo carregar os `arounds`, `before`, `helpers` e `runs` num arquivo.js principal e as rotas separadamente.

Como eu posso fazer isso? Require.js?

Exemplo da estrutura do meu código:

```
(function($) {

    var app = $.sammy(appCallback);

    function appCallback() {

        this.use('Template');
        this.element_selector = '#partials';

        this.around(callback)

        this.get('/#rota1', //callback)
        this.get('/#rota2', //callback)
        this.get('/#rota3', //callback)
        this.get('/#rota3', //callback)

        this.bind('algum-evento-da-rota1', //callback)
        this.bind('algum-evento-da-rota2', //callback)
        this.bind('algum-evento-da-rota3', //callback)
        this.bind('algum-evento-da-rota4', //callback)

    }

    //run aplication
    app.run('#/');

})(jQuery)
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17348123/using-sammyjs-with-requirejs

Comment: Conseguiu resolver?

Comment: @durtto, sim. Criei meu próprio framework de carregamento ajax. Cansei.

Comment: Entendo. Tente elaborar uma resposta para sua pergunta. Assim outras pessoas poderão ser ajudadas.

Comment: Resolveu seu problema?